# XAMARIN Button with Label and image inside / mainpage=navigation page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am fairly new and inexperienced. I have two questions. First: what would the xaml code in xamarin look like for such a button? The blue one should be the button. The button should contain a text and a picture. So it should also work that when the image or text is clicked, the button is actually clicked.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c93mA.png)
Second: my app has two sides. The start page is MainPage and the other page is Page1. I can switch to Page1 using a button on MainPage. I looked at a tutorial and in App.xaml.cs "MainPage = new MainPage ();" was made to "MainPage = new NavigationPage (new MainPage ());". Why was that done? Why does the page change via a button click not work differently?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osBCR.png)
Since it was coded to "MainPage = new NavigationPage (new MainPage ());" , there is a blue bar at the top of my MainPage. How can I remove this bar or make it white?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9xMK.png)

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting, and please do NOT post code or errors as image.

Comment: Please do not post multiple questions in one post, and pay attention to formatting of the text in your question. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Anyway, I think these links might help you:
1) Button with image and text --> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44988312/button-with-image-and-text-and-text-bellow-the-image-how)
2) How to remove NavigationBar --> [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-remove-navigation-bar-for-navigation-page-in-xamarin-forms/)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question:

There is no such control now, but you can do this by using a [Frame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/frame) and adding an **Image** and **Label** to it，then you could add a [TapGestureRecognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap) to the Frame.

like:

```
 <Frame CornerRadius="20"  HorizontalOptions="Start" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="120" BackgroundColor="Blue" Padding="40">
      <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" >
           <Image Source="heart.png"></Image>
           <Label Text="hello world" BackgroundColor="Red" ></Label>
       </StackLayout>
       <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
          <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"> 
          </TapGestureRecognizer>
       </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
 </Frame>
```

handle the click event in code behind:

```
 private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //do something
    }
```

For the second question:

1)To move from one page to another, an application will push a new page onto the navigation stack.The `NavigationPage` class provides a hierarchical navigation experience where the user is able to navigate through pages, forwards and backwards, as desired. The class implements navigation as a last-in, first-out (LIFO) stack of Page objects.

2)The top blue bar we call it NavigationBar.If you want display it,you could set `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);` in your MainPage.xaml.cs like:

```
public MainPage()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);      
   }
```

or set it in the MainPage.xaml like：

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
         x:Class="YourNamespace.MainPage">

 ....
 </ContentPage >
```

You could look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical for more details.